# chart js rotate label text on radar chart - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I have Chart js radar diagram with 24 labels.

I need to rotate every next label text to 15 degrees from previous: 'Label 1' is on the top and it's vertical, 'Label 2' rotated on 15 degrees clockwise etc.

Is there some option for this?

Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Radar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Chart as ChartJS, RadialLinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Filler, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(LineElement, PointElement, RadialLinearScale, Filler, Tooltip, Legend);

const data = {
  labels: ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5", "Label 6",    "Label 7", "Label 8", "Label 9", "Label 10", "Label 11", "Label 12", "Label 13", "Label 14", "Label 15", "Label 16", "Label 17", "Label 18", "Label 19",    "Label 20", "Label 21", "Label 22", "Label 23", "Label 24"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 5, 59, 90, 81, 56, 65, 59, 0, 81, 56, 65, 59, 90, 81, 56],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};

const options = {
  scales: {
    r: {
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
      angleLines: {
        display: true,
        color: "#90B7DA",
        borderDash: [11, 10],
        borderDashOffset: 5,
        lineWidth: 1
      },
      angle: 115,
      suggestedMin: 0,
      suggestedMax: 100,
      pointLabels: {
        font: {
          family: "Open Sans",
          size: 10,
          weight: "300"
        },
        color: "#90B7DA"
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
};

const RadarChart = () => <Radar data={data} options={options} />;

export default RadarChart;
```

Comment: I figured out how to achieve this in [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538302/1762224) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to modify the `drawPointLabels` function in Chart.js' `radialLinear` scale.

See: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v4.2.1/src/scales/scale.radialLinear.js#L201

You will need to apply a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) to the canvas context prior to calling `renderText`.

There is a way you can extend scales without hacking the library code, see: [New Axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html). You could possibly extend the `RadialLinearScale` and modify how it draws the labels.

The rotation angle would based on: `i / labelCount * 360`

---

## Update

I have created a custom `RadialLinearScale` that overrides the `drawPointLabels` logic.

You can view the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-custom-radial-qj8pxi

As I mentioned above, you will need to translate the origin and rotate along it to render the labels correctly:

```js
let origin = { x, y: y + plFont.lineHeight / 2 };

ctx.translate(origin.x, origin.y);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI * 2 * (i / labelCount));
```

Here is the full source:

### App.jsx

This is the entry point of the application where we render `<CustomRadarChart>`.

```
import CustomRadarChart from "./CustomRadarChart";

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Custom Radar Chart</h1>
    <CustomRadarChart />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

### CustomRadarChart.jsx

This is our custom `<Radar>` implementation.

Its associates the following with the chart:

- Controller: `<Chart type="derivedRadar">` (optional)
- Scale: `options.scales.r.type = derivedRadialLinearScale`

```
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from "chart.js";
import CustomRadarController from "./CustomRadarController";
import CustomRadialLinearScale from "./CustomRadialLinearScale";

// Regiser the basics
ChartJS.register(LineElement, PointElement, Filler, Tooltip, Legend);

// Register custom controller and scale
ChartJS.register(CustomRadarController, CustomRadialLinearScale);

const data = {
  labels: ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5", "Label 6", "Label 7", "Label 8", "Label 9", "Label 10", "Label 11", "Label 12", "Label 13", "Label 14", "Label 15", "Label 16", "Label 17", "Label 18", "Label 19", "Label 20", "Label 21", "Label 22", "Label 23", "Label 24"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: [65, 59, 90,81, 56, 5, 59, 90, 81, 56, 65, 59, 0, 81, 56, 65, 59, 90, 81, 56],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};

const options = {
  scales: {
    r: {
      type: "derivedRadialLinearScale",
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
      angleLines: {
        display: true,
        color: "#90B7DA",
        borderDash: [11, 10],
        borderDashOffset: 5,
        lineWidth: 1
      },
      angle: 115,
      suggestedMin: 0,
      suggestedMax: 100,
      pointLabels: {
        font: {
          family: "Open Sans",
          size: 10,
          weight: "300"
        },
        color: "#90B7DA",
        backdropColor: "#FFFF00",
        backdropPadding: 2,
        borderRadius: 4
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
};

const CustomRadarChart = () => (
  <Chart type="derivedRadar" data={data} options={options} />
);

export default CustomRadarChart;
```

### CustomRadarController.jsx

This is optional, but demonstrates how we can customize the drawing of the data points.

```
import { RadarController } from "chart.js";

// https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types
class CustomRadarController extends RadarController {
  draw() {
    //super.draw(arguments);
    const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    const meta = this.getMeta();
    for (let i = 0; i < meta.data.length; i++) {
      const point = meta.data[i];
      const { x, y } = point.getProps(["x", "y"]);
      const { radius } = point.options;
      ctx.strokeRect(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

CustomRadarController.id = "derivedRadar";
CustomRadarController.defaults = RadarController.defaults;

export default CustomRadarController;
```

### CustomRadialLinearScale.jsx

This is where the magic happens. I copied-over a few private functions from the `RadialLinearScale` class. This is required to override the label drawing.

Caveat: Since `drawPointLabels` is a private function called from `drawGrid`, we must re-implement everything associated with it. If the library gets updated, this class may need to be updated in conjunction.

```
import { RadialLinearScale } from "chart.js";
import {
  TAU,
  addRoundedRectPath,
  isNullOrUndef,
  renderText,
  toFont,
  toPadding,
  toTRBLCorners
} from "chart.js/helpers";

const DEBUG = false;

function drawPointLabels(scale, labelCount) {
  const {
    ctx,
    options: { pointLabels }
  } = scale;

  for (let i = labelCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const optsAtIndex = pointLabels.setContext(scale.getPointLabelContext(i));
    const plFont = toFont(optsAtIndex.font);
    const { x, y, left, top, right, bottom } = scale._pointLabelItems[i];
    const { backdropColor } = optsAtIndex;

    let origin = {
      x,
      y: y + plFont.lineHeight / 2
    };

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate(origin.x, origin.y);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI * 2 * (i / labelCount));

    const padding = toPadding(optsAtIndex.backdropPadding);

    if (!isNullOrUndef(backdropColor)) {
      const borderRadius = toTRBLCorners(optsAtIndex.borderRadius);

      ctx.fillStyle = backdropColor;

      const backdropWidth = right - left + padding.width;
      const backdropHeight = bottom - top + padding.height;
      const backdropLeft = -backdropWidth / 2 - padding.left;
      const backdropTop = -backdropHeight / 2 - padding.top;

      if (Object.values(borderRadius).some((v) => v !== 0)) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        addRoundedRectPath(ctx, {
          x: backdropLeft,
          y: backdropTop,
          w: backdropWidth,
          h: backdropHeight,
          radius: borderRadius
        });
        ctx.fill();
      } else {
        ctx.fillRect(backdropLeft, backdropTop, backdropWidth, backdropHeight);
      }
    }

    renderText(
      ctx,
      scale._pointLabels[i],
      -padding.left,
      -padding.top,
      plFont,
      {
        color: optsAtIndex.color,
        textAlign: "center",
        textBaseline: "middle"
      }
    );

    if (DEBUG) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "hsla(180, 100%, 80%, 0.667)";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    }

    ctx.restore();
  }
}

function drawRadiusLine(scale, gridLineOpts, radius, labelCount, borderOpts) {
  const ctx = scale.ctx;
  const circular = gridLineOpts.circular;

  const { color, lineWidth } = gridLineOpts;

  if ((!circular && !labelCount) || !color || !lineWidth || radius < 0) {
    return;
  }

  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  ctx.setLineDash(borderOpts.dash);
  ctx.lineDashOffset = borderOpts.dashOffset;

  ctx.beginPath();
  pathRadiusLine(scale, radius, circular, labelCount);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function pathRadiusLine(scale, radius, circular, labelCount) {
  const { ctx } = scale;
  if (circular) {
    // Draw circular arcs between the points
    ctx.arc(scale.xCenter, scale.yCenter, radius, 0, TAU);
  } else {
    // Draw straight lines connecting each index
    let pointPosition = scale.getPointPosition(0, radius);
    ctx.moveTo(pointPosition.x, pointPosition.y);

    for (let i = 1; i < labelCount; i++) {
      pointPosition = scale.getPointPosition(i, radius);
      ctx.lineTo(pointPosition.x, pointPosition.y);
    }
  }
}

// https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html
class CustomRadialLinearScale extends RadialLinearScale {
  // https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/scales/scale.radialLinear.js
  drawGrid() {
    const ctx = this.ctx;
    const opts = this.options;
    const { angleLines, grid, border } = opts;
    const labelCount = this._pointLabels.length;

    let i, offset, position;

    if (opts.pointLabels.display) {
      drawPointLabels(this, labelCount);
    }

    if (grid.display) {
      this.ticks.forEach((tick, index) => {
        if (index !== 0) {
          offset = this.getDistanceFromCenterForValue(tick.value);
          const context = this.getContext(index);
          const optsAtIndex = grid.setContext(context);
          const optsAtIndexBorder = border.setContext(context);

          drawRadiusLine(
            this,
            optsAtIndex,
            offset,
            labelCount,
            optsAtIndexBorder
          );
        }
      });
    }

    if (angleLines.display) {
      ctx.save();

      for (i = labelCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const optsAtIndex = angleLines.setContext(this.getPointLabelContext(i));
        const { color, lineWidth } = optsAtIndex;

        if (!lineWidth || !color) {
          continue;
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;

        ctx.setLineDash(optsAtIndex.borderDash);
        ctx.lineDashOffset = optsAtIndex.borderDashOffset;

        offset = this.getDistanceFromCenterForValue(
          opts.ticks.reverse ? this.min : this.max
        );
        position = this.getPointPosition(i, offset);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.xCenter, this.yCenter);
        ctx.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
}

CustomRadialLinearScale.id = "derivedRadialLinearScale";
CustomRadialLinearScale.defaults = RadialLinearScale.defaults;

export default CustomRadialLinearScale;
```

Comment: You're my hero :)